# data is not deleted after click on Delete Button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I created view where i listed my all records and i wanted to delete particular record after click on delete  Button . But my record is deleted.
Following is the code-

Controller code-

```
  public ActionResult Faqdelete()
        {
            var res = dbobj.tbl_FAQ.ToList();
            return View(res);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Faqdelete(int id)
        { 
            var res = dbobj.tbl_FAQ.Where(x => x.FAQ_ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            dbobj.tbl_FAQ.Remove(res);
            dbobj.SaveChanges();
            var Faqdata = dbobj.tbl_FAQ.ToList();
            return View("Faqdelete",Faqdata);
        }

 - View page Code-

@model IEnumerable<ClassOne_SampleProject.Models.tbl_FAQ>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Faqdelete";
}
<h2>Faqdelete</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FAQ_Question_Answer)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(item.FAQ_Question_Answer)
        </td>
        <td>
           <a href="@Url.Action("Faqdelete",new { item.FAQ_ID})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Please tell me where exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your anchor tag as

```
      <td>
       <a href="Url.Action("Faqdelete", "somecontroller", new { id = item.FAQ_ID })" 
         class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> 
    </td>
```